# Can't change js code. how to call a function in js loop or write a function

Tags: javascript

I am making a e-comers site.
https://colorlib.com/wp/template/onetech/ in this theme I am writting my own php code and changing some js.
But I face a problem and can't know how to solve this.
My html code was
`<div class="product_fav"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></div>`
and js was `

```
        function initFavs()
{
    var fav = $('.product_fav');
    fav.on('click', function()
    {

            fav.toggleClass('active');


    });
```

}`

I change this html code to

```
<div class="product_fav"><i class="pro fas fa-check"></i></div> <span id="txtHint"></span>
```

and js to `

```
         function initFavs()
{


    var fav = $('.product_fav');
    var faav = $('.pro');
    faav.on('click', function()
    {
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                      };
                      var xxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      xxhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                         document.getElementById("wili").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                      };

            if(faav.hasClass('fa-times'))
             {
                faav.removeClass('fa-times');
                faav.addClass('fa-check');
                fav.toggleClass('active');
                fav.removeClass('deactive');

                xhttp.open("GET", "addfavorite.php?no=" + no + "&id=" + id + "", true);
                xhttp.send();
                xxhttp.open("GET", "totalfavorite.php?no=" + no + "", true);
                xxhttp.send();
            }

            else if(faav.hasClass('fa-check') && fav.hasClass('active'))
            {
                faav.addClass('fa-times');
                faav.removeClass('fa-check');
                fav.toggleClass('deactive');
                fav.removeClass('active');

                xhttp.open("GET", "removefavorite.php?no=" + no + "&id=" + id + "", true);
                xhttp.send();
                xxhttp.open("GET", "totalfavorite.php?no=" + no + "", true);
                xxhttp.send();
            }
            else if(faav.hasClass('fa-check'))
            {
                faav.removeClass('fa-times');
                faav.addClass('fa-check');
                fav.toggleClass('active');
                fav.removeClass('deactive');

                xhttp.open("GET", "addfavorite.php?no=" + no + "&id=" + id + "", true);
                xhttp.send();
                xxhttp.open("GET", "totalfavorite.php?no=" + no + "", true);
                xxhttp.send();
            }

    });


}`
```

for this page http://shop.virusincbd.com/product.php
but I can't convert this code(html same) `

```
function initFavs()
{
    // Handle Favorites
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('product_fav');
    for(var x = 0; x < items.length; x++)
    {
        var item = items[x];
        item.addEventListener('click', function(fn)
        {
            fn.target.classList.toggle('active');

        });
    }
}`
```

for this page http://shop.virusincbd.com/

Comment: so what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, But failing again and again.

Comment: i didnt understand, can you just explain what you are trying to do

Comment: please go to this page http://shop.virusincbd.com/product.php and press the button which is right side of "Add to Cart" and please go to this page shop.virusincbd.com and take the mouse over a product. Hope you will understand

Answer (score 0):

You need to change from `$('.pro').on('click'` to `$('.product_fav').on('click'`

here is the working example:

https://codebrace.com/editor/b1c10075d

Comment: I want to say how to change 2nd code which is work as like as 1st